# What's faster (Field is not null or Field is not null) or (isnull(field,0) + isnull(field,0) != 0)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to only process rows that have at least one field with a value.

with a table like

```
create table #Temp
(
    Id int,
    cnt1 int,
    cnt2 int,
    cnt3 int,
    cnt4 int,
    cnt5 int
)
```

which one of the following two queries is faster?

```
select 
    *
from
    #Temp
where
    (cnt1 is not null or cnt2 is not null or cnt3 is not null or cnt4 is not null or cnt5 is not null)
```

or

```
select 
    *
from
    #Temp
where
    isnull(cnt1,0) + isnull(cnt2,0) + isnull(cnt3,0) + isnull(cnt4,0) + isnull(cnt5,0) != 0
```

I don't want results where all fields are equal to zero so the second query isn't a problem for me.

Also, is there a better (easier to read) way to do either query?

Comment: _"which one of the following two queries is faster?"_ [race the horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: If the answer is obvious because of the way the two are processed, I would rather get an answer based on actual knowledge than on me groping in the dark and possibly making a mistake due to improper testing methods.

Comment: Well, they're not the same query for one thing. What if all those fields are `0`, or happen to add up to `0`, but none of them is `NULL`?

Comment: @mypetlion I already stated that I don't care if they all add up to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there'll be a truly "good" query for this. No matter what you do, it still amounts to a series of `OR` conditions, and that rarely runs well. I suggest this:

```
select 
    *
from
    #Temp
where coalesce(cnt1, cnt2, cnt3, cnt4, cnt5) is not null
```

But you should *try it* on your database, with your actual data, resources, indexes, and load, and see what works best.

Answer (score 2):

The first query is seargable, the second one is not.

This means that if there are any indexes that SQL Server might be able to use to optimize the query, it can use them with the first question but not with the second one, and in that case, the first question will be faster.

With no relevant indexes, You should [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) (as Tim wrote in his comment).

Comment: I'd be suprised if the indexes are setup to support the OR option in a meaningful way.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is interested more about a general rule than on this specific query, but yes, all these `OR` conditions might make the indexes meaningless anyway for this query.